# LLL for quadratic forms

Tags: algorithms, integer-lattices, diophantine-approximation

It is quite easy to use the [LLL algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm) to find approximate solutions to linear/multilinear forms, and I am able to do that. However, I am trying to understand how the [LLL algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm) is used to approximate solutions to quadratic forms, which is used to find rational approximations.

> [image: paper excerpt]

In this small excerpt, the paper uses the [LLL algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm) to find rational approximations for real numbers(as one of the applications of the LLL algorithm) by representing the approximation as a quadratic form.

Since $x$ and $y$ are commutative, the expansion of $q(x,y)$ is

$$\left(M\bar{\alpha}^2+\frac{1}{M}\right)x^2+My^2-2M\bar{\alpha}xy$$

Here the coefficient of $xy$ is $-2M\bar{\alpha}$. However, the paper uses $-M\bar{\alpha}$, which I'm not quite sure why. Furthermore I've tried using the LLL algorithm on this lattice, but it failed to find rational approximations

Using a slightly modified matrix - $$\begin{pmatrix}\bar{a}^2M+1/M&-2\bar{a}M\\-2\bar{a}M&M\end{pmatrix}$$

The shortest vector found is still quite a poor rational approximation of $\bar{a}/2$.

So how could I use LLL on a quadratic form, or more generally any polynomial to find small roots?

Paper: https://simond.users.lmno.cnrs.fr/maths/lll25_Simon.pdf

---

**Appendix**

Let $\bar{a}=3.14159265358979\approx\pi$, $M=10^{10}$

$$\begin{pmatrix}\bar{a}^2M+1/M&-\bar{a}M\\-\bar{a}M&M\end{pmatrix}$$
After LLL:
$$\begin{pmatrix}37590&69064\\-174394&87912\end{pmatrix}$$
which are far from approximating $\bar{a}$

Using the 'modified' matrix,

$$\begin{pmatrix}\bar{a}^2M+1/M&-2\bar{a}M\\-2\bar{a}M&M\end{pmatrix}$$
After LLL:
$$\begin{pmatrix}-26967662134&-42831853072\\-6283185307&10000000000\end{pmatrix}$$
which kind of approximate $\frac{\bar{a}}{2}$ ($2\times\frac{42831853072}{26967662134}\approx3.17653438842212$, albeit very poorly)
which are far from approximating $\bar{a}$

Alternatively, I've tried approximating using a linear form(which I'm familiar with using LLL on):

Consider
$$x\bar{\alpha}-y=0$$

Construct the LLL matrix as

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&aM\\0&1&M\end{pmatrix}$$
After LLL,
$$\begin{pmatrix}33102&103993&-3940\\113&355&-302110\end{pmatrix}$$

Which indeed gives 2 approximations for $\pi$, $\frac{103993}{33102}=[3; 7, 15, 1, 292]$ and $\frac{355}{113}=[3; 7, 15, 1]$.